# Is there any equivalent function for an sql query: from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(${TABLE}.dt,"yyyyMMdd") in aws athena)

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, looker

I changed Looker database connection from fast access to Athena. However the fast access is using spark SQL, which is no longer work in Athena. The sql: from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(${TABLE}.dt,"yyyyMMdd")) works with fast access but not in Athena. So I would like to find the equivalent function for this in AWS athena, which return the same result in same data type.

Comment: Can you pos the input format and expected output format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your question exactly what data type you want, but I'm guessing you want a `TIMESTAMP`. The input looks like it's a compact ISO date, e.g. "20190204".

To parse that input into a `TIMESTAMP` in Athena you can do `date_parse(${TABLE}.dt, '%Y%m%d')`. That function returns a `TIMESTAMP`. You can also use `parse_datetime(${TABLE}.dt, 'yyyyMMdd')` if you prefer Java/JodaTime format strings.

You can find all the date and time functions supported by the version of Presto that Athena currently uses here: https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html